# Generate rectangular graph edges dynamically when we know number of vertices

Tags: c#, graph

Imagine we have 4 vertices (1,2,3,4), and I save them in array that way:

```
    var vertices = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var edges = new[]{Tuple.Create(1,2), Tuple.Create(2,4), Tuple.Create(4,3), Tuple.Create(4,1), Tuple.Create(3,2), Tuple.Create(3,1) };
```

Now it will look like this:

[image]

but what if I have more vertices, say 100? How should i generate it? will the loop be linear or not?
if i use something like this:

```
 List<Tuple<int,int>> edges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    for (int i=1; i<vertices.Length-1; i++)
    {
        edges.Add(Tuple.Create(i, i+1));
    }
```

I will eventually just get outline of the graph right? 
[image]

I can't figure out how to make intersections, like 1 to 3, 2 to 4.
Or if i have graph that is 100 vertices in width and 50 vertices in height, or is not necessarily rectangle?

*If you will need some more information i will add it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i use something like this…I will eventually just get outline of the graph right?

Correct.

> How should i generate it?

If I understand your question correctly, you just want all the possible combinations of vertexes. This is simple:

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> edges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

for (int i = 1; i < vertices.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vertices.Length; j++)
    {
        edges.Add(Tuple.Create(i, j));
    }
}
```

In other words, this is just a variation on the [Handshake Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

> will the loop be linear or not?

As you can see above, definitely not. It is O(n^2).